# Excluding a specific string of characters in a str()-function

Tags: python, string

A small issue I've encountered during coding.

I'm looking to print out the name of a .txt file.
For example, the file is named: verdata_florida.txt, or verdata_newyork.txt
How can I exclude .txt and verdata_, but keep the string between? It must work for any number of characters, but .txt and verdata_ must be excluded.

This is where I am so far, I've already defined filename to be input()

```
print("Average TAM at", str(filename[8:**????**]), "is higher than ")
```

Comment: try `"verdata_florida.txt".split("_")[1].split(".")[0]`

Comment: Why are you calling `str()`? If your filename is already text, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `str.split()` on strings. For example:

```
s = 'verdata_newyork.txt'

s.split('verdata_')
# ['', 'florida.txt']

s.split('verdata_')[1]
# 'florida.txt'

s.split('verdata_')[1].split('.txt')
['florida', '']

s.split('verdata_')[1].split('.txt')[0]
# 'florida'
```

Answer (score 2):

3 ways of doing it:

using `str.split` twice:

```
>>> "verdata_florida.txt".split("_")[1].split(".")[0]
'florida'
```

using `str.partition` twice (you won't get an exception if the format doesn't match, and probably faster too):

```
>>> "verdata_florida.txt".partition("_")[2].partition(".")[0]
'florida'
```

using `re`, keeping only center part:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(".*_(.*)\..*",r"\1","verdata_florida.txt")
'florida'
```

all those above must be tuned if `_` and `.` appear multiple times (must we keep the longest or the shortest string)

EDIT: In your case, though, prefixes & suffixes seem fixed. In that case, just use `str.replace` twice:

```
>>> "verdata_florida.txt".replace("verdata_","").replace(".txt","")
'florida'
```

Comment: What an answer! Great job on the alternatives! : )

Comment: thanks. The question is quite basic, so the answer _has_ to be less basic :)

Comment: There's even more ways to do this tbh, seeing as it's a quite basic operation. using replace() for example. I'd say OP hasn't done much research before asking.

Comment: well, according to the way OP's question is formulated, it looks like both `verdata_` and `.txt` are always present. Either way, I was only stating that there's so many ways to do this and that OP could have solved this on his own easily.

Comment: @Verv had I read this more carefully I wouldn't have answered... thx for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want it to split on the first `_` and the last `.` you can use slicing and the `index` and `rindex` functions to get this done. These functions will search for the first occurrence of the substring in the parenthesis and return the index number. If no substring is found, they will throw a `ValueError`. If the search is desired, but not the `ValueError`, you can also use `find` and `rfind`, which do the same thing but always return `-1` if no match is found.

```
s = 'verdata_new_hampshire.txt'
s_trunc = s[s.index('_') + 1: s.rindex('.')]  # or s[s.find('_') + 1: s.rfind('.')]

print(s_trunc)  # new_hampshire
```

Of course, if you are always going to exclude `verdata_` and `.txt` you could always hardcode the slice as well.

```
print(s[8:-4])  # new_hampshire
```

Comment: this solution is probably the most performant, because it doesn't create temporary strings. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just split string by dot and underscore like this:

```
string filename = "verdata_prague.txt";
string name = filename.split("."); //verdata_prague
name = name[0].split("_")[1]; //prague
```

or by replace function:

```
string filename = "verdata_prague.txt";
string name = filename.replace(".txt",""); //verdata_prague
name = name[0].replace("verdata_","")[1]; //prague
```